# Установка текста в jTextField

Tags: swing

Появилась проблема. интерфейс на swing. В нем несколько форм jtexfield.
На формы повешено следующее:

```
portTextField.setDocument(new PortDocument()); //устанавливаем ограничение на ввод в поле

private static class PortDocument extends PlainDocument { //класс для ограничения длинны ввода для порта
        @Override
        public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {
            String chars = "0123456789";
            if (chars.contains(str)) {
                if (getLength() < 5) { //порт не более 5 символов (0-65535)
                    super.insertString(offs, str, a);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Вот при попытке сделать

```
portTextField.setText(String.valueOf(port));
```

после запуска значения не появляются в поле. Хотя передаются цифры, в данном документе вполне дозволенные для ввода.
Вопрос. Как ограничить в поле возможность набора только цифр и не больше 5 в длинну, при этом при иметь возможность вставлять в это поле значения через код?

Ниже полный код:

```
 public SettingFrame(String host, int port, int start, int end) /*throws HeadlessException*/ { //конструктор окна со считанными параметрами
        jFrame = this; //устанавливаем соответсвие для удобства
        hostTextField.setText(host); //устанавливаем значение хоста
        portTextField.setText(String.valueOf(port)); //устанавливаем значение порта
        if (start ==0 && end == 0) { //если режим ND не активирован
            availableDB.setSelected(false);
            startNDTextField.setEnabled(false);
            endNDTextField.setEnabled(false);
        }else { //если режим ND активирован
            availableDB.setSelected(true);
            startNDTextField.setEnabled(true);
            endNDTextField.setEnabled(true);
            startNDTextField.setText(String.valueOf(start));
            endNDTextField.setText(String.valueOf(end));
        }
        init(); //инициируем


 private void init() { //инициация. Общая для обоих конструкторов
        jFrame.add(rootPanel); //добавляем к фрейму панель
        startNDTextField.setDocument(new NDDocument()); //устанавливаем ограничение на ввод в поле
        endNDTextField.setDocument(new NDDocument()); //устанавливаем ограничение на ввод в поле
        portTextField.setDocument(new PortDocument()); //устанавливаем ограничение на ввод в поле
        this.pack(); //устанавливаем размеры
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //перемещаем окно в центр рабочего стола
        this.setResizable(false); //запрещаем изменять размер окна
        this.setVisible(true); //отображаем окно
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //устанавливаем функцию кнопки закрытия - выход из программы
...
```

Минимальный достаточный самовоспроизводимый метод:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTextField jTextField = new JTextField();
        jTextField.setText("12");
        System.out.println(jTextField.getText().length());
        jTextField.setDocument(new PortDocument());
        System.out.println(jTextField.getText().length());

    }

    private static class PortDocument extends PlainDocument { //класс для ограничения длинны ввода для порта
        @Override
        public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {
            String chars = "0123456789";
            if (chars.contains(str)) {
                if (getLength() < 5) { //порт не более 5 символов (0-65535)
                    super.insertString(offs, str, a);
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: покажите в коде, то место где вы вызываете `setText`.

Comment: добавил полный конструктор и метод после конструктора. init сократил, опустив инициацию слушателей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Устанавливайте значение после того как установили **setDocument**. Так как **setDocument** выкидывает старое значение.

В вашем случае вызов `portTextField.setText(String.valueOf(port))` должен быть после `init()`.

Устанавливать значение надо после установки документа.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTextField jTextField = new JTextField();
        System.out.println(jTextField.getText().length());
        // устанавливаете документ
        jTextField.setDocument(new PortDocument());
        // устанавливаете значение
        jTextField.setText("12");
        System.out.println(jTextField.getText().length());
    }

    private static class PortDocument extends PlainDocument { //класс для ограничения длинны ввода для порта
        @Override
        public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {
            String chars = "0123456789";
            if (chars.contains(str)) {
                if (getLength() < 5) { //порт не более 5 символов (0-65535)
                    super.insertString(offs, str, a);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: нет, не помогает. Все равно после компиляции поле остается пустым. Ошибок так же не выпадает... Делал проверку - выводил текст в консоль из переменной, он точно там есть, в метод приходит как нужно

Comment: добавил архив с проектом, для запуска достаточно запустить client.Client - данные читает с clientconfig.cfg

Comment: написал тестовый метод, разобрался в чем ошибка, но вот как обойти - не знаю. Проверка организована по вхождение в строку. Когда мы пишем с клавиатуры - символы проверяются по очереди. При попытке вставить строку целиком - она целиком же проверяется на вхождение в эталон, и потому не проходит... Как ы изменить условия проверки...

Comment: Там 2 добавления значения. Одно до документа, одно после и вывод на консоль для сравнения результата. В итоге первый результат затирается после создания документа, а второй прописывается как нужно, если проходит проверку документа. До этого у меня не проходилась именно проверка документа, которую я и исправил. Ну и да, метод Init() у меня действительно нужно перенести вверх, за это спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

Нашел решение. Формат документа следующий:

```
private static class PortDocument extends PlainDocument { //класс для ограничения длинны ввода для порта
        @Override
        public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {
            String chars = "0123456789";
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                if (!chars.contains(str.substring(i, i + 1))) return;
            }
            if (getLength() < 5) { //порт не более 5 символов (0-65535)
                super.insertString(offs, str, a);
            }
        }
    }
```

Теперь проверяет и ставит корректно

Comment: нет. ваш документ в вашем минимальном пример работать не будет. проблема не в документе, а в том что вы присваиваете его после, того как присвоили значение. и все затирается.

Comment: удалите этот ответ. он не правильный.

Comment: Там 2 добавления значения. Код в основном посте в конце. Одно до документа, одно после и вывод на консоль для сравнения результата. В итоге первый результат затирается после создания документа, а второй прописывается как нужно, если проходит проверку документа. До этого у меня не проходилась именно проверка документа, которую я и исправил. Ну и да, метод Init() у меня действительно нужно перенести вверх, за это спасибо!